# Is it possible to select certain elements without iterating through the array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects, each of which has the property `:cow` either set to `false` or `true`:

```
animals = [
  {
    id: 1,
    cow: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    cow: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    cow: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    cow: false
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    cow: false
  }
]
```

I need to select all members of the array that pass a condition without iterating through every element of the array.

Is it possible?

I tried:

```
notCows = animals.reject { |a| !a[:cow] }
notCows = animals[0, 1, 2]
```

which doesn't work.

Comment: no - but is there something else in the problem statement that makes you think it should be?

Comment: Unless you're not telling us everything and the rails tag means that the array comes from the DB, in which case you can write a query that will filter out the elements not matching your condition.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think about writing a query to pull the data straight from the db.

Comment: No, you cannot do that, and your question is too trivial that it does not make sense. If you need to select **all** elements satisfying some condition, you need to look through **all** elements. How can you know if an element satisfies a condition without looking at it?

Comment: "which doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible. In order to find all elements that satisfy a certain condition, you need to look at all elements to see whether they satisfy that condition. It is simply logically not possible to find all elements of a collection without iterating through all elements of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, use [`Enumerable#select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) (which scans the all the member of the collection, by the way):

```
animals.select { |animal| animal[:cow] }
#=> [{:id=>1, :cow=>true}, {:id=>2, :cow=>true}, {:id=>3, :cow=>true}]
```

Or the opposite:

```
animals.select { |animal| !animal[:cow] }
#=> [{:id=>4, :cow=>false}, {:id=>5, :cow=>false}]
```

The returned results are still Ruby objects: Arrays of Hashes.

---

As alternative you can group by status ([`Enumerable#group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)):

```
animals.group_by { |a| a[:cow] }
#=> {true=>[{:id=>1, :cow=>true}, {:id=>2, :cow=>true}, {:id=>3, :cow=>true}], false=>[{:id=>4, :cow=>false}, {:id=>5, :cow=>false}]}
```

Comment: This will still iterate through all elements of the collection, though, which the OP explicitly does not want.